# ggplot2: error when superposing two layers

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

The following describes in a simplified manner an issue into which I run often but never get it to work. It has to do with superposing layers with different information.

Any help is appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
            year = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2000,2001,2002,2001,2002,2003),
            meas = c(1.1,1.2,NA,1.4,2.1,1.9,1.8,3.1,3.0,3.3))

df$id   = as.factor(df$id)
df$year = as.factor(df$year)

tib = as.tbl(df)
```

which produces the tibble:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
       id   year  meas
   <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
 1      1   2000   1.1
 2      1   2001   1.2
 3      1   2002    NA
 4      1   2003   1.4
 5      2   2000   2.1
 6      2   2001   1.9
 7      2   2002   1.8
 8      3   2001   3.1
 9      3   2002   3.0
10      3   2003   3.3
```

Presently, I compute the median of the meas-ures for each year in the cross section.

```
tib2 = tib %>% group_by(year) %>%       
    summarise(medi=median(meas,na.rm=T))
tib2
```

Which gives as expected

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
    year  medi
  <fctr> <dbl>
1   2000  1.60
2   2001  1.90
3   2002  2.40
4   2003  2.35
```

So far so good. Now, I create my first plot

`p = ggplot(tib, aes(x = year, y = meas, group = id, color = id))
     p = p + geom_line()
     p`

which produces

[image]

On the other hand, the following produces a set of fat dots as it should

```
p1=ggplot(tib2, aes(x = year, y = medi)) + geom_point(colour = 'red', size = 3)
p1
```

[image: Red dots]

I try however to place the red dots in the first figure like so:

```
p = p + geom_point(data = tib2, aes(x = year, y = medi), colour = 'red', size = 3)
p
```

This is where I get the error:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
>   Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, 
>   the arguments imply different numbers of lines : 4, 0

Remark: I noticed that the missing value induces a cut in the red line which I might wish to interpolate. When I replace the NA by some value, the error persists however.

Comment: shouldn't that last code chunk be `p = p + geom_point(...)`?

Comment: The "object of type function" error suggests that `aes(x = year...)` might be misinterpreted (is `lubridate` loaded by any chance?) What happens if you do `ggplot() + geom_line(data = tib2, aes(x = year, y = medi), colour = 'red', size = 3)`

Comment: Lubridate is not on. I made a mistake copying. The error persists with p=p+geom_point.

Comment: ggplot()+geom_point(data = tib2, aes(x = year, y = medi), colour = 'red', size = 3) produces the second figure. It is when I add p=p+geom_point(data = tib2, aes(x = year, y = medi), colour = 'red', size = 3) that I get the bug. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The "object of type function" error relates to the `dplyr::id()` function.

When you assign an aesthetic in the `ggplot` call it applies to all the plot, and while it is correctly interpreted in the first geom in the `tib` dataframe context, the `tib2` context does not have it, so it produces an error.

You can pass the relevant `aes` to the single `geom`, or you can use `inherit.aes = FALSE` on the '`tib2` geom':

```r
library(ggplot)

ggplot(tib) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = year, y = meas, group = id, color = id)) +
  geom_point(data = tib2, aes(x = year, y = medi), size = 3, color = 'red')


ggplot(tib, aes(x = year, y = meas, group = id, color = id)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = tib2, aes(x = year, y = medi), size = 3, color = 'red', inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Or even more elegantly, specify the `aes` that are common in the `ggplot` call and the others where needed:

```r
ggplot(tib, aes(x = year)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = meas, group = id, color = id)) +
  geom_point(data = tib2, aes(y=medi), size = 3, color = 'red')
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-08 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: To avoid mistakes, would it make sense to follow the following rule: put the first dataframe into ggplot. Put aesthetics in geom as they come along. To change dataframe, put new dataframe+aes in new geom?

Comment: That's what I usually do. Also changing `data` in geom should be done sparingly

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
ggplot(tib, aes(x = year, y = meas, group = id, color = id)) +
   geom_line() +
   stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom="point", aes(group=year), colour = 'red', size = 3)
```

[image]

or use as Dash2 recommended

```
ggplot() +
   geom_line(data=tib, aes(x = year, y = meas, group = id, color = id)) +
   geom_point(data = tib2, aes(x = year, y = medi), colour = 'red', size = 3)
```

Comment: thanks! This fixes the bug. The mistake must be that by defining within ggplot the data = tib it persists as I introduce the new data. This implies one cannot just add layers, from the beginning the intention should be clear. Unless there is a parameter I missed. Thanks again.